# Where can i find these symbols?

Tags: vue.js, symbols

Can someone help me? Where can i find these symbols?

[Symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjFv6.png)

Answer (score 1):

Those are just abbreviations for <= and &&. To get less or equal to in Ascii this is the code: `ALT-243 = ≤`

Answer (score 0):

They are ligatures in a font called Fira Code. The arrow is made up from `=>`, and the less-than sign from `<=`.